# SPARQL to SQL query rewriting engine

Tags: sql, sparql, semantic-web

I am looking for ontology based data access (OBDA) system capable of SPARQL to SQL query rewriting to convert the following SPARQL query:

`SELECT ?interface ?ip  WHERE { ?interface network:hasIpAddress ?ip. ?ip network:containedWithin "192.168.1.0/24". }`

or, alternatively:

`SELECT ?interface ?ip WHERE { ?interface network:hasIpAddress ?ip. FILTER(?ip IN "192.168.1.0/24"). }`

... to the following SQL query:

`SELECT interface, ip FROM interfaces WHERE ip_address << "192.168.1.0/24"`

*Notes:

1. "<<" operator in SQL WHERE statement is specific to PostgreSQL type "inet": https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-net.html
2. For a general case, "192.168.1.0/24" may be considered as parameter that must be passed down from SPARQL to SQL filtering engine.*

I would be grateful if you could advise solutions for the problem.

I explored Ontop, Sparqlify and a few others alike. They seem to be based on graph materialization approach that assumes "exportability" of SQL database data as triples. To answer query in question query rewriting seems to be needed to employ special index of SQL database to find matching records.

Comment: neither Ontop nor Sparqlify need a materialization step of the triples, they both rewrite the SPARQL query to a SQL query based on your provided mappings. Indeed, Ontop might not cover the magic `<<` for IP addresses, but I'd simply ask for help on the Ontop mailing list how difficult it would be to add such a non-standard SQL operator for IP addresses

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I posted the question to Ontop and Sparqlify communities. Regarding query rewrite, it seems to me that R2RML mappings on which the rewrite is based assumes "exportability"

Comment: I decided to give expanded comment on "exportability". I could not find a way to map the filter of the query in question neither in R2RML nor in Otop/Sparqlify proprietary mappings. R2RML-based query rewrite seem to require that all query components have corresponding table columns. If this is the case, then filter is out of scope of R2RML-based mappings and must be done elsewhere (in SQL view, for example). This works for static filters and excludes dynamic filters as in the query in question. I hope that I am wrong and it can be mapped somehow.